# How to get access to the full-size photo after Uri after save

Tags: android, android-camera

As documentation describe here [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) I'm trying to get access to full-size image save by intent. I have followed every step in the documentation as I understand still. Now I'm wondering how to get access to that file `onActivityResult()`. because `Intent` on that method is null.

**Activity.java**

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.chathurangashan.cameraintent",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }

    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data.hasExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)) {
                    Uri uri = (Uri) data.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chathurangashan.cameraintent">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.chathurangashan.cameraintent"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

file_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.example.chathurangashan.cameraintent/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

file_path.xml is save under resource folder in 'res'

**PS:** I know I can get the bit map in `onActivityResult()` directly as documentation describe under **"Get the thumbnail"** but it's not returning full size image. it's a low quality version of the captured image.

Comment: "it's returning null intent onActivityResult" -- you may want to edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace. Note that `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is a value that you supply on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. It is not part of the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

your **dispatchTakePictureIntent()** should return an intent so that you can get **Uri** path as extra, back using `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` as key.

```
    private Intent dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            "com.example.chathurangashan.cameraintent",
                            photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                }
            }
           return takePictureIntent;
        }
```

now you should start your intent like this and store it somewhere globally to be used later.

```
intentImage = dispatchTakePictureIntent();
startActivityForResult(intentImage, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

now in your onActivityResult do something like this.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (intentImage.hasExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)) {
                //your uri from saved intent 
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(intentImage.getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is'n that the same thing with function returning Intent and calling startActivityForResult outside ? Any way I tried Same result. and That `return Intent` should be `return takePictureIntent `, right?

Comment: yeah, but i hope you got the idea. we put the uri in the intent and when result came let extract from the same intent.